# Turning auto-update off on a specific app via ADB?

Tags: android, mobile, adb

I am currently running a batch file to remove bloatware from these new Motorola phones we are getting for our users.

One app the batch file disables is the NFL Mobile App.  However, when the phone does application updates from the play store it re-enables the NFL app!

I think this can be fixed by turning off auto-updates for the NFL mobile application in the apps section of the settings.  Would be nice if I could do this through an ADB command.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I figured out why it was updating the disabled application.

I believe it has to do with when I signed into a google account on the device and when I ran my batch file.  If I sign into a Google account before I run the batch file, it seems to tell the Google Play Store to disable auto-updates on the applications my batch file Disables. If I run the batch file before I log into a Google account, the Play Store wont be accessible, therefor will not set the auto update to off.  So when I log into a google account and update applications, the disabled apps that get updates will re-enable themselves.